# How do I take screenshot for Windows Phone 8.1 in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit, writeablebitmapex

I know how to do this in Silverlight but I can't find enough information on how to do this in WinRT.

I read that [WinRT XAML Toolkit](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) may be able to help but the exact component, `WinRT XAML Toolkit - Composition` does not seem to be compatible with Windows Universal App. I am currently developing for Windows Phone 8.1 part.

[WinRT XAML Toolkit for Windows Phone 8.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.windowsphone) does not seem to have something like `WriteableBitmap.Render` method either.

I've also read that the `blit` method in [WriteableBitmapEx](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) may be able to help but I couldn't find any example on how to achieve this.

Any deas?

Comment: Why is the downvote? Is this not a programming question?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out ;)

Comment: Downvotes with no comment are rude, I agree. Just a comment for the Toolkit - I intentionally reduced support and visibility of the composition library since 8.1 added `RenderTargetBitmap` which addresses most of the same scenarios. I left it in the toolkit sources though as an inspiration and in case at any point it turns out that `RenderTargetBitmap` doesn't support some important scenario. For example - it could be modified to be used to add GPU-powered pixel shader effects to your UI if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RenderTargetBitmap](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20648.using-the-rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-store-apps-with-xaml-and-c.aspx) to create image from your UIElement which contains in VisualTree.

```
  var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
  await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);

  var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

  var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
  var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, stream);
  encoder.SetPixelData(
      BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
      BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
      (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
      (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
      logicalDpi,
      logicalDpi,
      pixels.ToArray());

  await encoder.FlushAsync();

  return renderTargetBitmap;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler to use if you want to display it, in order to save you must do as the answer above:

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(RenderedGrid);
RenderedImage.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
```